# systemv libvirtd fails to start on Debian Jessie

Tags: kvm-virtualization, libvirt, debian-jessie

After a reboot, `libvirtd` refuses to start using systemv without producing any useful errors:

```
systemctl status libvirtd.service
● libvirtd.service - Virtualization daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/libvirtd.service; enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: start-limit) since Mon 2016-11-28 17:03:16 GMT; 1min 6s ago
     Docs: man:libvirtd(8)
           http://libvirt.org
  Process: 8295 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/libvirtd $libvirtd_opts (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 8295 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Nov 28 17:03:16 localhost systemd[1]: Failed to start Virtualization daemon.
Nov 28 17:03:16 localhost systemd[1]: Unit libvirtd.service entered failed state.
Nov 28 17:03:16 localhost systemd[1]: libvirtd.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
Nov 28 17:03:16 localhost systemd[1]: Stopping Virtualization daemon...
Nov 28 17:03:16 localhost systemd[1]: Starting Virtualization daemon...
Nov 28 17:03:16 localhost systemd[1]: libvirtd.service start request repeated too quickly, refusing to start.
Nov 28 17:03:16 localhost systemd[1]: Failed to start Virtualization daemon.
Nov 28 17:03:16 localhost systemd[1]: Unit libvirtd.service entered failed state.
```

Trying to use `journalctl` to get the output:

```
journalctl -xn
-- Logs begin at Mon 2016-11-28 16:02:48 GMT, end at Mon 2016-11-28 17:03:16 GMT. --
Nov 28 17:03:16 localhost libvirtd[8295]: /usr/sbin/libvirtd: initialization failed
Nov 28 17:03:16 localhost systemd[1]: libvirtd.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Nov 28 17:03:16 localhost systemd[1]: Failed to start Virtualization daemon.
-- Subject: Unit libvirtd.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit libvirtd.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is failed.
Nov 28 17:03:16 localhost systemd[1]: Unit libvirtd.service entered failed state.
Nov 28 17:03:16 localhost systemd[1]: libvirtd.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
Nov 28 17:03:16 localhost systemd[1]: Stopping Virtualization daemon...
-- Subject: Unit libvirtd.service has begun shutting down
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit libvirtd.service has begun shutting down.
Nov 28 17:03:16 localhost systemd[1]: Starting Virtualization daemon...
-- Subject: Unit libvirtd.service has begun with start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit libvirtd.service has begun starting up.
Nov 28 17:03:16 localhost systemd[1]: libvirtd.service start request repeated too quickly, refusing to start.
Nov 28 17:03:16 localhost systemd[1]: Failed to start Virtualization daemon.
-- Subject: Unit libvirtd.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit libvirtd.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is failed.
```

Also doesn't help much.
Interestingly, when I execute the daemon directly, it works without errors or warnings, only `[info]` and works without a problem!

1. How can I find out what is causing this?
2. How can I figure what makes the service fail but the direct daemon succeed?

**__EDIT__**

I've tried as suggested with `journalctl -u libvirtd.service -b` as suggested:

```
Nov 28 16:03:00 localhost systemd[1]: Starting Virtualization daemon...
Nov 28 16:03:01 localhost libvirtd[1090]: /usr/sbin/libvirtd: initialization failed
Nov 28 16:03:01 localhost systemd[1]: libvirtd.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Nov 28 16:03:01 localhost systemd[1]: Failed to start Virtualization daemon.
Nov 28 16:03:01 localhost systemd[1]: Unit libvirtd.service entered failed state.
Nov 28 16:03:01 localhost systemd[1]: libvirtd.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
Nov 28 16:03:01 localhost systemd[1]: Stopping Virtualization daemon...
Nov 28 16:03:01 localhost systemd[1]: Starting Virtualization daemon...
Nov 28 16:03:01 localhost libvirtd[1167]: /usr/sbin/libvirtd: initialization failed
Nov 28 16:03:01 localhost systemd[1]: libvirtd.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Nov 28 16:03:01 localhost systemd[1]: Failed to start Virtualization daemon.
Nov 28 16:03:01 localhost systemd[1]: Unit libvirtd.service entered failed state.
Nov 28 16:03:01 localhost systemd[1]: libvirtd.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
Nov 28 16:03:01 localhost systemd[1]: Stopping Virtualization daemon...
Nov 28 16:03:01 localhost systemd[1]: Starting Virtualization daemon...
```

But the output isn't really helpful, it only points to the daemon not starting, but no details as to why it fails.

Comment: Try `journalctl -u libvirtd.service` and see if the full log for the service has more information

Comment: And add `-b` to get only information from the current boot.